# Is using nested for loops good practice?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tic-tac-toe

I am working on a tic-tac-toe game, everything is going smoothly but I was wondering if there was a better way to carry out the following code:

```
def straight_check(play_board, item):
    inc_up = 1
    inc_down = 1
    for num in range(3):
        for second in range(3):
            if play_board[second][num] == 'x':
                if inc_up == 3:
                    return True
                inc_up += 1
            else:
                continue
            if play_board[num][second] == 'x':
                if inc_down == 3:
                    return True
                inc_down += 1
            else:
                continue

    return False
```

This function takes in the board for the game (a 3x3 nested list) along with the users char (x or o). This function checks if the users char occurs 3 times in a row on the board (horizontally or vertically). Is there another way I could do this without using a nested for loop along with variables? Also, is this kind of programming along with the size of the programming good practice?

Comment: From the Zen of Python: "Flat is better than nested". In any event -- this is more of a question for [codereview.se] rather than here.

Comment: There is nothing fundamentally "bad" about nesting loops, and i see nothing wrong with your code.  Just be mindful of what you're doing inside those loops - like instantiating large objects - since there's a potential for creating a performance problem.

Comment: Right. It's not bad in that it's a thing you should *never* do, but it's bad in that it's a thing you shouldn't do *when a more efficient algorithm that avoids it is available*.

Comment: "Is eating mushrooms good for you?" - Not if they're poisonous. Same goes with nested loops - depends on what you use them for.

Comment: @djk47463 it's only O(n^2) on the number of "rows" (or "columns"), but it is O(N) on the number of items total.

Comment: @djk47463 O(n^2) when n is 1 million is no different to O(n) if n = 1 million^2. If the board is `m * m` and you need to evaluate `m^2` possibilities, the nesting of the code is just an implementation artifact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there are some issues. You should reset the counters inside the outer loop (or you'll keep incrementing counts from previous failed chcks) and also remove the `else: continue` parts or you will skip column checks if there is no `item` in the corresponding row:

```
def straight_check(play_board, item):
    for x in range(3):
        # reset the counters in inner loop
        cnt_hori, cnt_vert = 0, 0  
        for y in range(3):
            if play_board[x][y] == item:
                cnt_hori += 1
                if cnt_hori == 3:
                    return True
            if play_board[y][x] == item:
                cnt_vert += 1
                if cnt_vert == 3:
                    return True
    return False
```

Nothing inherently wrong with the nested loops in general (since you know in advance that this is only a 3x3 matrix). Note, however, that there are the built-in functions [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) and [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) as well as the `zip(*...)` transpositioning pattern that you can use to some effect in order to shorten your code and (maybe) make it more readable:

```
def straight_check(play_board, item):
    if any(all(x == item for x in row) for row in play_board):
        return True
    if any(all(x == item for x in col) for col in zip(*play_board)):
        return True
    return False
```

You can think of this in terms of natural language: Does it hold for "any" row that "all" items in it are 'x', etc.?